# Get value of child object's using a variable referencing that key

Tags: javascript

I have below object and I can reference key e as in the following:

```js
var obj = {
"id": 100,
"date": "2021",
"d": "D",
"e": {
    "e1": "E"
},
"f": {
    "f1": "F"
}}

console.log(obj.e); // returning { e1: 'E' }
```

I want to get the value by using the object key as below and input [Key] always be a that place.

```js
{
"d": "D",
"e": "E",
"f": "HardCode FF"
}
```

Input, that I am receiving,

```
{"id":100,"date":"2021","d":"D","e":{"e1":"E"},"f":{"f1":"F"}}
```

Output, that I am expecting,

```
{"d":"D","e":"E","f":"HardCode"}
```

I tried the above approach but seems I am getting the child json obj only.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+access+nested+object+value+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. It is not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: What you want to try?

Comment: I've no clue what you actually need, maybe [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) or [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) or [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) help?

Comment: Added the extra details in question.

Comment: Where is "_HardCode_" coming from? It's not included in the input data ..?

Comment: "*I tried the above approach*" - I don't see any code there?

Comment: You write "*using a variable referencing that key*" but I don't see any such variable. Is it dynamic? Or do you just want to `return {d: input.d, e: input.e.e1, f: 'Hardcode FF'};`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add conditionally if you know the keys you want

```js
const obj = { "id": 100, "date": "2021", "d": "D", "e": { "e1": "E" }, "f": { "f1": "F" } };

const newObj = {
 ...(obj.e && {e: obj.e.e1}),
 ...(obj.d && {d: obj.d}),
  f: "HardCode"
}
console.log(newObj)
```

We can reduce

```js
const obj = { "id": 100, "date": "2021", "d": "D", "e": { "e1": "E" }, "f": { "f1": "F" } };

const newObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,[key,val]) => {
  if (key === "f") acc["f"] = "HardCode";
  else if (["id","date"].includes(key)) return acc;
  else if (typeof val === "object") acc[key] = Object.values(val)[0] 
  else acc[key]=val;
  return acc;
},{})

console.log(newObj);
```

We can destruct

```js
const obj = { "id": 100, "date": "2021", "d": "D", "e": { "e1": "E" }, "f": { "f1": "F" } };

const { id, date ,  ...newObj } = obj;
newObj.f = "HardCode"
newObj.e = newObj.e.e1; // not elegant
console.log(newObj);
```

To not have to code the `e` key, we can just get all first entries

```js
const obj = { "id": 100, "date": "2021", "d": "D", "e": { "e1": "E" }, "f": { "f1": "F" } };

const { id, date ,  ...newObj } = obj;
newObj.f = "HardCode"
Object.entries(newObj).forEach(([key,val]) => { if (typeof val === "object") newObj[key] = Object.values(val)[0] })


console.log(newObj);
```

Alternatively use Object.assign with some filtering, but for your usecase, my code should be enough

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the output {"d":"D","e":{"e1":"E"},"f":"hardcode"}

though I am expecting {"d":"D","e":"E","f":"HardCode"}

Comment: @Karl, Check this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/xxXGmqd

Comment: @Karl Not sure if both `f` and `e` key are known - if they are, see new solution. If e is not known, we can take the first entry  of whatever is left

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. so I was missing this part. Now it's working.

Comment: @Karl see update

Comment: I think second solution is more accurate because if I'll not have the e key then 1st code will break. so I think 2nd code is the best answer in this case. Thanks @mplungjan

Comment: the reduce is more code but also more customisable

Comment: @Karl If you KNOW the names of the keys, we can add then conditionally

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the object and mutate the rest, you can get the result you're expecting. Below is the code which I tried.

```js
let obj = {"id":100,"date":"2021","d":"D","e":{"e1":"E"},"f":{"f1":"F"}};
let {id, date, ...rest} = obj;
rest.e = rest.e.e1;
rest.f = "HardCode";
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this solution is also working as expected.